# The native mongoDb driver for node.js fails at removing a specific doc

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following problem:

In my application I have a model for all my sessions in the mongoDb-DB.

The idea is, that the model inherits from the abstract Model...so i don`t have to write all the standart functions again...like getting the collection etc.

**So that is the Code of my sessionModel:**

```
var baseProvider = require('./abstract/model').abstractProvider;
var queryString = require('querystring');
var _collection = 'sessions';

sessionProvider = function() {
     baseProvider.apply(this, [_collection]);
};

sessionProvider.prototype = new baseProvider(_collection);

sessionProvider.prototype.deleteSession = function(sessionId){
    this.getCollection(function(err,sessionCollection){
       sessionCollection.remove({_id: sessionId},function(err,result){
           console.log(err,result);
       });
    });

}

exports.sessionProvider = sessionProvider;
```

**Then in my baseProvider(my "abstract Model"):**

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSON;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

abstractProvider = function(collectionName) {
  var dbName = process.settings['shopconfig'].db.dbName;
  var dbHost = process.settings['shopconfig'].db.dbHost;
  var dbPort = process.settings['shopconfig'].db.dbPort;
  this.db= new Db(dbName, new Server(dbHost, dbPort, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
  this.db.open(function(){});
  this.collectionName = collectionName;
};


abstractProvider.prototype.getCollection= function(callback) {
  this.db.collection(this.collectionName, function(error, abstractCollection) {
    if( error ) callback(error);
    else callback(null, abstractCollection);
  });
};

exports.abstractProvider = abstractProvider;
```

**I`ve shortend the codeparts to the important parts, don`t be irritated.**

The problem is, that the removefunction is executed, the callback gets called but the err-object and the result-object are undefined.

Is it false to call remove on the collection that way?

Im a bit puzzled...cause everything else works just fine...inserting stuff, updating, etc.

**Edit:** SessionID is filled btw, i looked at that already, cause i thought maybe it would be empty...but isn`t. Even calling remove() without criteria fails...

thanks for your time. =)

Answer (score 0):

Is sessionId an instance of ...db.bson_serializer.ObjectID or are you shoving it into a session structure that converts it to a hex string? The latter happens with Cookie and Redis stores in Express, and cookie storage in general.  Might be worth checking if you have a db reference in there:

```
sessionId = (typeof sessionId == "string")
    ? new db.bson_serializer.ObjectID(sessionId)
    : sessionId
```